# Spring boot: submodule dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multi-module spring boot application. I have organized it in such way that it contains `web` module which has `@SpringBootApplication` class and several other modules which are  being imported by `web` module (e.g. `batch-jobs` module).

`web` module contains all dependencies from spring boot:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
...
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
etc...
```

I wonder whether I should include all spring-boot-starter dependencies into this modules or it's better to have *pure* spring dependencies like here:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-context'
  compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl'
  compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core'
  ...
  testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test'
  testCompile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
}
```

Those dependencies are taken anyway from upper `dependency-management` configuration. Which approach is better? Can you please advise here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post will be flagged as opinion-based but anyway:

My thoughts on this topic are (or were if I look at spring boot) to explicitly name the dependencies you actively use in your code (and the specific modules). But with spring boot you cannot really *match* the dependency in your modules against the starters in the 'project'. Of course you may know that a starter-web will provide mvc from looking in the dependencies outside your project but I think that it will be hard for others to get into the definitions if the project 
grows and maintain them.

Pure speculative: What if a starter gets an update and drops a dependency in favour of another? Just to give an example: LibX provided by vendorA is now switched to vendorB. You will still have a JSON dependency to vendorA in your module config but also vendorB gets in your classpath. If they have the same fully qualified name...(bam)

You could extract several starters like persistence related ones to the persistence module and web to web and so on.

Comment: Yes. you are right regarding missing dependencies, but anyway I will check build functionality when updating versions of spring boot.